# Looped <input> entry to database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `<select>` tag with option values in loop.

[Attached is the screenshot of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RABx.png)

In this image you can see I have a dropdown of the CTO. Now when I select a CTO from dropdown and click its corresponding Assign button then I don't get any result in my database. Here is my code for the shown page:

```
while($variable=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 $i++;
$_SESSION['k']=$i;
$_SESSION['link']=array();
$_SESSION['link'][$i]=$variable["name"];
mysql_select_db('users');
$sql="create table if not exists administrator(
app_sno int auto_increment primary key,
app_name varchar(50) not null,
cto_assigned varchar(50),
status varchar(10) default 'NA')";
$name=$variable["name"];
mysql_query($sql) or die('Error'.mysql_error());
$sql="insert into administrator(`app_name`)values('$name')";
mysql_query($sql) or die('ERROR'.mysql_error());
echo"<tr>
    <td>".$variable["application_type"]."</td>
    <td>localhost/nrdc_login/phase1/download.php?name=".$variable["name"]."   </td>";
echo  "<td>";   

?>


<form name="<?php echo 'cto'.$i;?>" method="post" action="enter_A.php">
<select name="<?php echo 'cto_assigned'.$i;?>">
    <?php
mysql_select_db('users');
$result1=mysql_query("select * from login where application_type='C'");
while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
    {   ?>
<option value="">SELECT</option>;
<option value="<?php echo $res["fname"].$res["lname"];?>"><?php echo   $res["fname"]." ".$res["lname"];?></option>;
   <?php 
    }?>
    </select>
<?php echo "</td>";?>
        <td>
<input type='hidden' name='hidden'>           
<input type=submit value='Assign' name="enter_A"></td>
</form>
<?php 

            echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
```

Also attached is the php code for database entry:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
session_start();
//if(isset($_POST["enter_A"]))
for($j=1;$j<=$_SESSION['k'];$j++)
{
//$i=$_SESSION['link'][$j];
{   
    if(isset($_POST['enter_A']))
    {
        //echo $i;
        mysql_select_db('users');
    $cto=$_POST['cto_assigned'.$j];
        echo $cto.'<br>';
    $sql="update `administrator` set cto_assigned='$cto'";  
    mysql_query($sql) or die('Error:'.mysql_error());
    }
    else{
        echo('Alerrt!!<br>');}
    }
} /*  else
{echo 'alert';
//header('location:login_A.php');
}*/
?>
```

Comment: This question is OK, but was let down a great deal with shouty caps demanding urgency, which is likely [why this has been downvoted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495).

Comment: @halfer: can you please give me a solution or help me get one.Need it urgently!

Comment: Ha ha, very good `:-)`

Comment: ... er, that was a joke, right?

Comment: (Aside: the query looks like it has a SQL injection vulnerability also).

Answer (score 0):

Your update query lacks a where clause,  meaning that right now, it will update ALL entries in that table with the new cto.